# How to set up dynamic allocation on Cloudera 5 in YARN?

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop-yarn, cloudera-cdh

I'm trying to run a Spark dynamic resource allocation on Cloudera 5 using Yarn.

In [Spark documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/job-scheduling.html#configuration-and-setup) the properties required to set on `yarn-site.xml` are missing from the Cloudera configuration interface. Even though I set manually those properties in `yarn-site.xml` and I add `yarn-shuffle.jar` to the classpath, the shuffling service is not working.

I got the following exception

> org.apache.hadoop.yarn.exceptions.InvalidAuxServiceException: The
>   auxService:spark_shuffle does not exist

Comment: The version the Cloudera that I was using was not supporting running Spark dynamic resource allocation on Yarn. I updated to the last version and it works.

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me:

If you have Cloudera deployed, go to cloudera manager (port 7180)
I have CDH 5.6.0

Go to YARN (MR2 Included) -> Configuration -> NodeManager Default Group -> Advanced

In the Textbox associated with "NodeManager Advanced Configuration Snippet (Safety Valve) for yarn-site.xml" paste the following:

```
<property>
    <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services</name>
    <value>spark_shuffle,mapreduce_shuffle</value>
  </property>
<property>
    <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services.spark_shuffle.class</name>
    <value>org.apache.spark.network.yarn.YarnShuffleService</value>
</property>
```

Click on Save Changes.
Actions -> Deploy client configuration
Actions -> Restart